# Throttle Pagerduty alerts

Tags: pagerduty

Is there a way I could throttle alerts in Pagerduty? What I want to achieve is that if some alert (e.g. with same summary or any other distinctive feature, which could be used as a key)is dispatched very often I'd like to get notified of it only once per X minutes.

Answer (score 1):

I think you're looking for the [Intelligent Alert Grouping](https://support.pagerduty.com/docs/intelligent-alert-grouping) feature. It's only available on certain plans, so you might not have it available on your account right now.

Alternately, you could try something like setting up [Event Rules](https://support.pagerduty.com/docs/rulesets) to group together the incidents based on some common field, and then setting up the service to [retrigger incidents after some set amount of time](https://support.pagerduty.com/docs/service-settings#section-acknowledgement-timeouts), even if they've been acknowledged.